# Save/Delete Local Object with RestKit on iPhone IOS

Tags: iphone, ios, core-data, restkit

I'm trying to store local objects (not mapped) with Core Data and Restkit but it doesn't work.

I created a NSManagedObject :

```
@interface JSONOrder : NSManagedObject

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSNumber * shopId;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSNumber * type;

@end
@implementation JSONOrder

@synthesize shopId;
@synthesize type ;

@end
```

Now i'm trying to save it :

```
JSONOrder * order = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"JSONOrder" inManagedObjectContext:[[RKObjectManager sharedManager].objectStore managedObjectContext]] ;
[order setShopId:_shopId];         
[order setType:_typeId];
[[RKObjectManager sharedManager].objectStore save] ;
```

When i try to get my object back :

```
NSLog(@"%@", [JSONOrder allObjects]) ;
```

My ARRAY is empty or I have Faulty object in it !!

Do you have any clue ?

Comment: Does my answer below work? if not can you provide details of the error message you see when it tries to save (You'll need to use the _error_ code portion I included to see the save error)

Comment: Yep ! Thanks a lot for your help ! :) I have another problem now ! I will describe it below :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you need to have to have:

```
 [[RKObjectManager sharedManager].objectStore.managedObjectContext save];
```

Alternatively do something like:

```
 // Save the MOC
 NSError* error;
 BOOL hasSaved = [order.managedObjectContext save:&error];
 #if DEBUG
 NSLog(@"INFO:{%s} CoreData has Saved: %@ (%d)\nerror:%@ | %@ | %@", __FUNCTION__, (hasSaved) ? @"YES" : @"NO", hasSaved, error, [error userInfo],[error localizedDescription]);
 #endif
```

... that's what I do anyway ;o)

Answer (score 1):

thanks to Herwr for this solution

```
[item setFavourite:[NSNumber numberWithBool:YES]];

        NSError *error=nil;

        [[Article managedObjectContext] save:&error];
        if (error) {
            NSLog(@"error saving favourite item");
        }else{
            NSLog(@"save successful");
        }
```

works like a charm for me.